# windows 8 bing maps pushpins moving when zoom in/out

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I'm developing a map for Windows 8 store using Bing Maps where i draw several atms and branches in the map, not using Pushpin but a control that i have created and they are putted in the respective Location. 
The problem is that when the zoom level is (for example) 13 the pins are a little far from their real location and when i zoom in the pins start to move to the real position.

Does anyone has any idea what should i do to fix the pins in their location despite the actual map zoom level?

This is my draw code for atms:

```
AgenciesMarkers Aginfo = new AgenciesMarkers(); 
Aginfo.Agclass = atm; 
Aginfo.ImageType = new BitmapImage(new Uri(typeSource, UriKind.Absolute)); 
Aginfo.Height = 65; 
Aginfo.Tapped += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedEventHandler(AGMarker_click); Aginfo.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 4); 
MapLayer.SetPosition(Aginfo, (new Location(atm.Latitude, atm.Longitude))); mapLayer.Children.Add(Aginfo); mapLayer.Margin = new Thickness(25, 0, 0, 0);
```

Using pushpin it happens the same thing.

Comment: I think you need to show us some code. Why do you use your own pins ? Can you reproduce issue using standard Pushpins ?

Comment: This is my draw code for atms:
`AgenciesMarkers Aginfo = new AgenciesMarkers();

            Aginfo.Agclass = atm;

            Aginfo.ImageType = new BitmapImage(new Uri(typeSource, UriKind.Absolute));
            Aginfo.Height = 65;
            Aginfo.Tapped += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedEventHandler(AGMarker_click);
            Aginfo.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 4); 

            MapLayer.SetPosition(Aginfo, (new Location(atm.Latitude, atm.Longitude)));
            mapLayer.Children.Add(Aginfo);
            mapLayer.Margin = new Thickness(25, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: I tried to use custom Pushpin but happens the same thing, pushpins moving :S

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting in comments !!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by default custom pushpins/user controls are positioned such that the Location aligns with the top left corner of the control. If you don't do anything to account for this you will see your pushpin drift to or from the location as you zoom in/out. One easy way to fix this is to add a negative margin on you user control such that it will align the control with the Location on the map. For example, if you want to center the user control over a Location, then set the margin so that it's x value equals -width of control/2 and the y value equals -height of control/2.

Comment: Could you please post a code sample, it will be much helpful. tnx.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post which explains how to handle this: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/correcting-anchoring-pushpins-to-the-map/